# Watch Later playlist url via YouTube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to get the link for a users watch later playlist using the YouTube api? I'm trying to generate a url to start playing the watch later playlist from the first video, so that the final link would be something like youtube.com/watch?v=videoID&list=playlist. I'm using the YouTube Data API v3.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, it looks like as of this month Google has deprecated access to the Watch Later playlist via the public API:

> The channel resource's contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory
>   and contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchLater properties now contain
>   values of HL and WL, respectively, for all channels. (The properties
>   are only visible to an authorized user retrieving data about the
>   user's own channel.)
>
> In addition, requests to retrieve playlist details (playlists.list) or
>   playlist items (playlistItems.list) for a channel's watch history or
>   watch later playlist now return empty lists. This behavior is true for
>   the new values, HL and WL, as well as for any watch history or watch
>   later playlist IDs that your API Client may have already stored.

See the [full revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with [mine](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#mine) = true.

Then from the channel response, you will get the [watchlater-playlistID](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchLater).

Comment: Yes, but this is the internal playlist ID that YouTube uses, with which you can fetch videos from this playlist using the API, but you can't use it in the link url. It just shows up with a video without a playlist if I do.

Comment: The watchlater playlist id returned is "WL", which now returns an empty list. Is there another way to get the internal watch later playlist id?

Comment: @Ignat - see my answer, it looks like this is no longer possible. I wish I knew why!