# How to list Watch Later list in APIv3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Since youtube APIv3 [revision on September 15, 2016](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-15-2016), the **Watch Later list id** cannot be found in `channels.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchLater` as it contains fixed string `WL`.

The revision states:

> ...
>
> The channel resource's contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory
>   and contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchLater properties now contain
>   values of HL and WL, respectively, for all channels.
>
> To be clear, these properties are only visible to an authorized user
>   retrieving data about the user's own channel. The properties always
>   contain the values HL and WL, even for an authorized user retrieving
>   data about the user's own channel. Thus, the watch history and **watch
>   later playlist IDs cannot be retrieved via the API.**
>
> ...

The last part is pretty intriguing since I can't imagine how to obtain my WL id, hence I can't list the videos I've saved for later.

I checked also [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/4xc8rp/youtubes_api_just_deprecated_getting_data_about_a/) and other SO questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239503/youtube-data-api-v3-playlistitems-update-not-working-for-watch-later-playlists), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891357/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-watch-later-playlist-using-youtube-api-v3), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975200/watch-later-playlist-url-via-youtube-api), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239503/youtube-data-api-v3-playlistitems-update-not-working-for-watch-later-playlists)) but without success. They usually suggest v2 or v3 before the mentioned revision.

The question: How can I obtain ids of my watch later videos?

Answer (score 4):

I can only confirm what you already stated. If it is deprecated form API it is not possible to retrieve videos form that particular playlist. It is bound to be some *ugly* web scraping solution if it is a matter of getting it done no matter the cost.